FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage not called on ios if no notification is send
I am working on flutter app android/ios. I have configured the firebase messaging part and it works just fine for android, but for ios it is working only partially.
If I send a message like this
{
    "message": {
      "token": "working_token",
      "notification": {
        "title": "Test Notification",
        "body": "This is a test message sent via FCM manually."
      },
      "data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    }
  }

I will get the notification with above text, but I want to use data only messages so I am trying to send something like this
{
    "message": {
      "token": "working_token",
      "data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    }
  }

but in this case the iOS is not calling the FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage function.
This are my settings in xcode

